# How to re-route a URL

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, routing

Is it possible to re-route a URL to an HTML file stored on the system?  I don't want to set up a network - I want it to all be controlled from one computer and only affect that one computer.

Example: When I visit `http://www.facebook.com/`, have it open `/home/username/Documents/facebook.html` instead of loading the actual URL.

I've seen it done using a Local Area Network, but I want it to only affect one computer and be controlled from that computer - I don't want my entire Wifi network to be affected.

Is this possible?

Edit: My computer is running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: You cannot redirect a hostname to a specific file.  You can redirect a hostname to your localhost in order to block that domain from being loaded.

Comment: Is it possible to put a file on the localhost?

Comment: Please add an OS tag. In principle, you can make your browser use a proxy, and that proxy can rewrite URLs. It doesn't have to do anything with LAN or WLAN.

Comment: @ChristianF97 no it isn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you're trying to do isn't as simple as redirecting to a file.

To explain: when browsing to www.facebook.com, you aren't actually browsing to a file. You're browsing to their web server, which then serves web pages to you. Yes, those web pages are stored in files (generally speaking), but the web server acts as an intermediary to serve them to you.

In order to redirect www.facebook.com to a file on your local computer, your computer needs to be running a web server of some sort. I could certainly provide instructions to do that. However, it sounds like you're simply trying to prevent someone from accessing Facebook on that computer.

The easiest way to accomplish that would be to add an entry to the hosts file on the computer.

For Windows, you can modify the hosts file this way:

1. Click on the Start menu. Type "notepad" to search for the Notepad
   application.
2. **IMPORTANT:** Right-click on "Notepad" in the search results and choose "Run as Administrator" from the menu. Notepad will open.
3. In Notepad, click the File menu and choose "Open".
4. Browse to the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` folder.
5. You probably won't see any files there. If not, select "All Files" from the dropdown menu that's just above the "Open" and "Cancel" buttons.
6. Select "hosts" from the file list.
7. Click the "Open" button to open the file.
8. Add the following line to the bottom of the file:

`127.0.0.1 facebook.com www.facebook.com`

9. Click the File menu and choose "Save".
10. It may ask you if you want to overwrite. If so, click "Yes".
11. Close Notepad.

For Linux, you can modify the hosts file this way:

1. Open a Terminal.
2. Type `sudo vi /etc/hosts`. Or you can replace `vi` with `nano`, if you prefer.
3. Add the following line to the bottom of the file:

`127.0.0.1 facebook.com www.facebook.com`

4. Save your changes and exit.

You're done. Now regardless of the user that logs in on the computer, they will get an error if they try to go to facebook.com or www.facebook.com.

Comment: Whoops I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - I'll edit the question

Comment: Then you can add the line in step 8 to the `/etc/hosts` file. This will accomplish the same thing.

Comment: I have updated my original reply to include Windows and Linux instructions (for completeness).